# Using Pexpect to Spawn Terminal Window and SSH command

Tags: python, macos, ssh, terminal, pexpect

I am trying to use Python and the Pexpect module to do two things:

1. Open multiple terminal windows (on Mac) to display outputs
2. Send a **separate** ssh command to each of the terminal windows (each will ssh into a different host, and run another command)

This is my current code:

```
import pexpect
import time
from subprocess import *

command = "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal ssh user@host"
ssh_tunnel = pexpect.spawn (command)

ssh_tunnel.expect ('Password:')
time.sleep (0.1)
ssh_tunnel.sendline ("password")
time.sleep (60) #
ssh_tunnel.expect (pexpect.EOF)
```

The problem that I am seeing is that I'm able to open up a new terminal application, however, no commands are running on that terminal.

I am also seeing an issue trying to spawn multiple windows.  When I try to do this:

```
ssh_tunnel = pexpect.spawn("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal")
ssh_tunnel.expect ('test')

ssh_tunnel2 = pexpect.spawn("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal")
ssh_tunnel2.expect ('test')
```

I only spawn one terminal window.

I have tried the subprocess module in python to spawn multiple terminal windows, and that works fine, however I know subprocess doesn't handle ssh as well as pexpect.

Subprocess Module code:

```
from subprocess import *

command = '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal'
new_terminal = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: pexpect is designed to work with CLI commands, not GUI apps.

Comment: Instead of `ssh_tunnel.expect (pexpect.EOF)` can you provide '$ ' to expect ?

Comment: *＋1* for asking an SSH question that has to do with programming and development.

Comment: @MaheshKaria Hi, I have tried to replace the expect statement with '$ ', however, the terminal spawn.  The application does start up, but the terminal doesn't pop up.

Comment: @pynexj Hi, I'm still looking into alternatives for this problem, and found some recommended like fabric.  Still, I'm testing if its possible in python or should I try it in bash or powershell.